# How to create GTK+4 Application on mac OS 11?

Tags: c++, c, bash, gcc, gtk4

So, I installed `gtk+4` with homebrew. I created `.C` file and wrote:

```cpp
// Include gtk
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void on_activate (GtkApplication *app) {
  // Create a new window
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  // Create a new button
  GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello, World!");
  // When the button is clicked, close the window passed as an argument
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_window_close), window);
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), button);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Create a new application
  GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new ("com.example.GtkApplication",
                                             G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (on_activate), NULL);
  return g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
}
```

*I copied "Hello, World!" program code from [www.gtk.org](http://www.gtk.org). I have error:*

```
g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4` && ./main
```

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gtk4/4.2.1/lib/libgtk-4.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pango/1.48.9/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pango/1.48.9/lib/libpango-1.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/lib/libcairo-gobject.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/harfbuzz/2.9.0/lib/libharfbuzz.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.42.6/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/lib/libcairo.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphene/1.10.6/lib/libgraphene-1.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.68.4/lib/libgio-2.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.68.4/lib/libgobject-2.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.68.4/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_g_application_get_type", referenced from:
      _main in main-0ae029.o
  "_g_application_run", referenced from:
      _main in main-0ae029.o
  "_g_object_unref", referenced from:
      _main in main-0ae029.o
  "_g_print", referenced from:
      _print_hello in main-0ae029.o
  "_g_signal_connect_data", referenced from:
      _main in main-0ae029.o
      _activate in main-0ae029.o
  "_g_type_check_instance_cast", referenced from:
      _main in main-0ae029.o
      _activate in main-0ae029.o
  "_gtk_application_new", referenced from:
      _main in main-0ae029.o
  "_gtk_application_window_new", referenced from:
      _activate in main-0ae029.o
  "_gtk_button_new_with_label", referenced from:
      _activate in main-0ae029.o
  "_gtk_window_get_type", referenced from:
      _activate in main-0ae029.o
  "_gtk_window_present", referenced from:
      _activate in main-0ae029.o
  "_gtk_window_set_child", referenced from:
      _activate in main-0ae029.o
  "_gtk_window_set_default_size", referenced from:
bozich@Antons-Mac-mini ass % gcc main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk4` `pkg-config --cflags gtk4`
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gtk4/4.2.1/lib/libgtk-4.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pango/1.48.9/lib/libpango-1.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pango/1.48.9/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/lib/libcairo-gobject.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/harfbuzz/2.9.0/lib/libharfbuzz.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.42.6/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/lib/libcairo.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphene/1.10.6/lib/libgraphene-1.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.68.4/lib/libgobject-2.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.68.4/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.68.4/lib/libgio-2.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_g_application_get_type", referenced from:
      _main in main-314cd7.o
  "_g_application_run", referenced from:
      _main in main-314cd7.o
  "_g_object_unref", referenced from:
      _main in main-314cd7.o
  "_g_print", referenced from:
      _print_hello in main-314cd7.o
  "_g_signal_connect_data", referenced from:
      _main in main-314cd7.o
      _activate in main-314cd7.o
  "_g_type_check_instance_cast", referenced from:
      _main in main-314cd7.o
      _activate in main-314cd7.o
  "_gtk_application_new", referenced from:
      _main in main-314cd7.o
  "_gtk_application_window_new", referenced from:
      _activate in main-314cd7.o
  "_gtk_button_new_with_label", referenced from:
      _activate in main-314cd7.o
  "_gtk_window_get_type", referenced from:
      _activate in main-314cd7.o
  "_gtk_window_present", referenced from:
      _activate in main-314cd7.o
  "_gtk_window_set_child", referenced from:
      _activate in main-314cd7.o
  "_gtk_window_set_default_size", referenced from:
      _activate in main-314cd7.o
  "_gtk_window_set_title", referenced from:
      _activate in main-314cd7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My machine is working on ARM64 (Apple Silicon M1). I think, therefore here's error, but how do I fix it?

// Maybe my english is not perfect, but I hope you understood me.
// Maybe question is strange, but plz help me.

Comment: You need to tell your compiler where to find the files and libraries.

Comment: It looks like your compiler is set up to build x86-64 binaries. Can you build any M1 executable (a hello world program)?

Comment: try running with arch -x86_64 g++ main.cpp ......